Slack bolt for javascript: Create files using output from an api response
I am building a slack app using slack bolt and I am fetching data from a certain endpoint. Is it possible to retrieve it and write it as a file. Something similar to fs.write on node?
This is what I want to achieve. Have tried it. Not working. It just doesn't do anything. I want to trigger it on a command.
const result = await certainEndPoint();

fs.writeFile('./file.txt', result, (err) => {
  // throw error if fails
})


Are you sure that it is actually getting to that point in the code? If not, you'll need to provide more code.

No error. Works fine. Pretty strange. I tried console logging inside.
P.S. using ngrok.

@asportnoy yes. It is working fine. The command is also working fine. I'm using that command to generate some data. That is also working fine on my slack workspace. Not sure what's causing the issue.
